# URL Segment Support macosx 10.6

Tags: apache, macos, expressionengine

does anyone knows how to activate URL Segment Support in Snow Leopard? I take I must add the AcceptPathInfo On directive to the httpd.config file in /private/etc/apache2 but I cant find the right way to do it. Should I set AllowOverride and go .htaccess instead? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`AcceptPathInfo` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) in the *server config*, *virtual host*, *directory* or  *.htaccess* [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context).

- *virtual host* context:

  Here’s an example for the virtual host *localhost*:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/localhost/"
      AcceptPathInfo on
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

  That will now apply to the whole virtual host.
- *direcory* context:

  If you just want to use it in specific directory, you can either use a `<Directory>` block in your server/virtual host configuration file:

  ```
  <Directory /Users/username/Sites/localhost/foobar>
      AcceptPathInfo on
  </Directory>
  ```
- *.htaccess* context

  Or, if you want to allow the `AcceptPathInfo` directive in .htaccess files, you need to set [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) `FileInfo` for that directory, e.g.

  ```
  <Directory /Users/username/Sites/localhost/foobar>
      AllowOverride FileInfo
  </Directory>

  # .htaccess file in /Users/username/Sites/localhost/foobar
  AcceptPathInfo on
  ```